# Adjacent extreme rays of a polyhedral cone

Tags: linear-programming, convex-cone

I am looking for an algorithm that could determine adjacent extreme rays of a polyhedral cone (extreme rays that share a face), given the set of inequalities defining the cone and an extreme ray for which the adjacent rays are to be determined. I was hoping there exist a python library that might already have coded up, but I could only find pycddlib, which seems to need to determine all extreme rays first. This seems inefficient to me: I was hoping there would be a method that doesn't neccesitate computing all extreme rays first.

Thank you for help!